# Routes not redirecting to static file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to serve index.html in docs/ subdirectory of public folder as static file. The index file should be served both at /index.html and / URLs.

Below is my `app.js` code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Below is my `routes.index` code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("comes in");
  //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/', 'docs/index.html'));
  //res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, './public') });
  res.sendFile('/docs/index.html');

});
```

When i run `localhost:3000`, it does not re-direct to `/docs/index.html` [static content]

Comment: Have you tried `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/docs/index.html'));` ?

Comment: So, do you want a redirect, or do you want to send file contents? Those are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/doc/index.html');
```